# YQL: how to get all cities from a country

Tags: json, yahoo, yql

I want to get all cities from a specify country using YQL.
Anybody knows the correct YQL to get all cities from a country ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for this is at http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/yql-tables.html#geo-places-children

However I've played around with this before and it's not as easy as you'd think.

For example you'd expect that a query like select * from geo.places.children where parent_woeid = 23424832 AND type = 'Town' would return all towns in Guam but it doesn't, it returns no results.

Selecting all children of Guam - select * from geo.places.children where parent_woeid = 23424832 gives you the administrative divisions, and from there you can query again to find the children of each admin.

However the world is a very complex place and it's a nightmare trying to do this for all countries as the admin types are different for each.

The best approach I found was to download the Geoplanet data and use the parent WOEIDs to work out the relationships, you can download it from here - http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/data/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply... I have downloaded the geoplanet data from your link... but now... how i can use this ? Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is to load the data into tables in your database, then use the parent WOEID to work up from Towns to Countries. The long answer would be too long for this comment box :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't download data updates anymore. Alternatively you have to drill down to administrative levels (depends on the country you choose - usually a county (not country) woeid is enough) and use the following model for your queries:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+geo.places.descendants+where+ancestor_woeid={yourcountywoeid}+and+placetype='Town'
```